# how to use json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm dealing with highcharts with dynamic data (values retrieved from database).
By writing a query i was able to retrieve the following data from the table

```
Item   2011   2012
pen     5      7
pencil  4      20
eraser  6      43
```

I want to store the above info in the following structure and pass it to another page

```
[{ name:'pen', data: [5,7]},{ name:'pencil', data: [4,20]},{ name:'eraser', data: [6,43]}]";
```

I want to push the above data to the drilldown highchart.

Is there a way i can generate in this format? I've tried using json_encode but unable to succeed.
Can i achieve this using json_encode?

**Updated**
I've tried in this way

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  $rows[]= $row;

  }
echo json_encode($rows);
```

and got

```
[{"Item":"pen","2011":"5","2012":"7"},{"Item":"pencil","2011":"4","2012":"20"},{"Item":"eraser","2011":"6","2012":"43"}]
```

Comment: `json_encode` encodes JSON, not the Javascript object expression (unquoted keys) you have there. Not that it matters, though.

Comment: Looks like a better approach would be to serialize the data.

Comment: @JohnConde i've updated some info.check out

Comment: @ven, in my answer I showed how to get the exact output you requested.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`json_encode` is a convenience method to convert an array into JSON format. To have the output you provided, you will need an array of arrays. Each sub-array has keys "name" and "data", where "name" is the Item column, and "data" is another array containing values from 2011 and 2012.

```
$results = mysql_query("...");
$arr = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    $name = $row['Item'];
    $data = array($row['2011'], $row['2012']);

    $arr[] = array('name' => $name, 'data' => $data);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Loop through the database results and put the results in an array
2. JSON encode the array